# Grant sudo permissions for nrpe to run the check as root

Tags: linux, nagios, nrpe

When I run `service httpd status` like root user I get `httpd (pid  2932) is running...` which is like expected.

Now, when I `su nrpe` and run the same cmd `service httpd status` I get `httpd dead but subsys locked`.

I'm kind of new to the Linux world but to me this smells like `nrpe` doesn't have the permissions to run this cmd so it gives mentioned output.

How can I grant sudo permissions to nrpe so it can run chis cmd as root?

I have a nagios plugin that checks httpd status and it gives `httpd dead but subsys locked` which is not what I need.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to edit your sudo file by typing visudo as the root user.

To allow your nrpe user to run service without needing a password you first need to comment out the following lines if they exist:

```
#Defaults targetpw
#ALL ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Then add the following line:

```
nrpe ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service
```

Now the nrpe user should be able to run "sudo service httpd status" without it asking for a password.

You should note though that this will give the nrpe user control to every service. If you're using Apache, you might want to try something like this instead:

```
nrpe ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/apache2ctl
```